# Using a Rewrite URL in a Plugin to Load a New Page in the Template

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm working on a plugin that I need to load some custom code.  However, I want it to load within the template, while still giving me the ability to change the page title, meta description, etc.

I've got a rewrite rule setup that looks like this:

```
function cc_rewrite_rules()
{
  add_rewrite_rule('^page/form/([^/]*)-([^/]*)?$',
       '/wp-content/plugins/cc-plugin/pages/form.php?sign1=$matches[1]&sign2=$matches[2]',
       'top'
  );
}
```

Anything I add to form.php loads, but it seems to load with whatever else exists at the base URL.  How can I construct this page so that it loads as a stand-alone file but using the active WordPress theme?

Also, how can I set the page title and meta description from within form.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add_rewrite_rule( $regex, $redirect, $after );
>
> ---
>
> **Rewrite rules to scripts other than index.php**
>
> The `$redirect` argument works slightly differently when redirecting to a custom PHP script because WordPress delegates these redirects to `.htaccess` instead of processing them itself. For this reason, querystring variables should be written like `$1` instead of `$matches[1]`.

Personally, I would use a rewrite rule pointing to `index.php`. In this way, the rule will also work outside of Apache.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se343855_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se343855_query_vars' );

function se343855_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^page/form/([^/-]*)-([^/]*)?$',
        //  Or maybe:
        // '^page/form/([^/-]*)(?:-([^/]*))?$',
        //
        'index.php?sign1=$matches[1]&sign2=$matches[2]',
       'top'
    );
}

function se343855_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push( $vars, 'sign1', 'sign2' );
    return $vars;
}
```

Load a custom template if the query variable is set (`sign1` or `sign2`):

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'se343855_template_include', 50 );

function se343855_template_include( $template )
{
    $sign1 = get_query_var('sign1', false);
    $sign2 = get_query_var('sign2', false);

    if ( $sign1 !== false || $sign2 !== false ) {
        // if this code is located in plugin file
        $template =  plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/pages/form.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Use [get_query_var()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to get value of `sign1` or `sign2`.

In `form.php` file you can use `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.